# How can I clone a class with all the values that are already set in it?

Tags: c#, .net

class example:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
}
```

using the class:

```
    Customer customer1 = new Customer();
    customer1.CustomerID = 1;
```

Now how can I create a customer2 class with all the values that are stored in customer1?

Comment: no inheritence. I initialize a class and I start feeding alot of information to it. now how to clone it with all the info that I have fed into it?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects-in-c-sharp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it manually:

```
var customer2 = new Customer { CustomerID = customer1.CustomerID };
```

You can implement `ICloneable` interface in `Customer` class:

```
public class Customer : ICloneable
{
    private int CustomerID { get; set; }

    public Customer Clone()
    {
        return new Customer { CustomerID = this.CustomerID };
    }

    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return this.Clone();
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
var customer2 = customer1.Clone();
```

You can serialize your object into XML/JSON and then deserialize it into new object, as described in this answer: [Deep cloning objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78612/1163867).

Or you can use reflection to get and copy all properties/fields values into your new `Customer` instance. It could have bad performance, but you'd have to measure it to make sure how bad it is.

**Edit**

One more way to do that: you can make reflection version faster using Expression Tree! Get all fields/properties and compile all necessary assignments at runtime using `Expression.Lambda`. After that every next `Clone` call will use compiled code so there will be no performance drawback at all. I've created `Clone<T>` extension method which does exactly that, using `Expression` class, static constructor and reflection. You can find the code on CodePlex: [CloneExtension.cs](https://marcinjuraszek.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#aLittleBitOfProgramming/CloneUsingExpressionTree/CloneExtension.cs)

Answer (score 1):

Either you use reflection to copy the values or you would want deep clone (ICloneable).

Comment: Ah, the irony. How sure are you that reflection really has a bad performance? :)

Comment: Like I said... it depends... If this operation is going to get called quite a bit in a tight loop... then it will add up.

Comment: His scenario is just copying the values.

Comment: And what if he needs to make millions of copies?

Comment: And what if one of the properties changed? Too lazy to refactor the changes that are going to be made.

Comment: And isn't that often the dilemma... elegance vs. performance.

Answer (score 1):

To extend [Marcin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20690292/80274), if all of your items in your class are value types or immutable types (`int`, `double`, `string`, ect.) you can just use [`MemberwiseClone()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This will create a [shallow copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy) of the original object, and if all your members are immutable there is no need to do a deep copy. This can be useful if you have many objects in your class you need to copy over.

```
public sealed class Customer : ICloneable
{
    private int CustomerID { get; set; }

    public Customer Clone()
    {
        return (customer)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return this.Clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: If all members are immutable, why create a clone? :)

Comment: @Thorarin Good question, because the members are immutable but the container class that stores them (`Customer`) is not. If I do `myCustomer2 = myCustmer1.Clone(); myCustomer2.CustomerID = 3` I do not want `myCustomer1` to be modified with the new value of `CustomerID`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you set the class up like so:

```
public class Customer
{
  private Customer Parent {get; private set;}

  private int _id;
  public int CustomerID
  {
    get { return Parent == null ? _id : Parent.CustomerID; }
    set
    {
      if(Parent != null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("...");

      _id = value;
    }

    public Customer()
    {
    }

    public static Customer Clone(Customer parent)
    {
      return new Customer{Parent = parent};
    }
}
```

This would create a immutable clone.  Now... if you need to be able to alter the values... then either take a different approach, or expand on it.